# Trying to create a Pong clone in JS, but the paddles won't interact with the ball

Tags: javascript, pong

I'm trying to create my own clone of Pong in Javascript following a guide. So far, I've managed to draw the canvas, create a ball and paddles, and I'm trying to see if the ball will interact with the paddles. The problem is that it won't interact with them. I'm not sure if I'm missing something code-wise, or if I'm completely blind to some huge error. All of the questions here on StackOverflow has either been in different coding languages or I haven't been able to understand them.

I'm grateful for any help that I can get!

```
var animate = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
function(callback) { window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60) }; 


var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var width = 900;
var height = 600;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

window.onload = function() {
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 animate(step);
};

var step = function() {
 update();
 render();
 animate(step);
};

var update = function() {
 ball.update(player1.paddle, player2.paddle);
};

Ball.prototype.update = function(spelare1, spelare2) {
 this.x += this.x_speed;
 this.y += this.y_speed;
 var top_x = this.x - 5;
 var top_y = this.y - 5;
 var bottom_x = this.x + 5;
 var bottom_y = this.y + 5;

if(this.y - 5 < 0 ) { 
 this.y = 5;
 this.y_speed = -this.y_speed;
} else if(this.y + 5 > 900) { 
 this.y = 450;
 this.y_speed = -this.y_speed;
}

if(this.x < 0 || this.x > 900) { 
 this.x_speed = 3;
 this.y_speed = 0;
 this.x = 450;
 this.y = 300;
}


if(top_x > 900){

if(top_y > (player2.y + player2.height) && bottom_y < player2.y && top_x > 
  (player2.x + player2.width) && bottom_x < player2.x) {

  this.x_speed = -3;
  this.y_speed += (player2.y_speed / 2);
  this.y += this.y_speed;
}
} else {
if(top_y < (player1.y + player1.height) && bottom_y < player1.y && top_x < 
(player1.x + player1.width) && bottom_x < player1.x) {
  // bollen nuddar player1
  this.x_speed = 3;
  this.y_speed += (player1.y_speed / 2);
  this.y += this.y_speed;
}
}
}; 

var render = function() {
 context.fillStyle = "black";
 context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
 player1.render();
 player2.render();
 ball.render();
}; 

function Paddle(x, y, width, height) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.width = width;
 this.height = height;
 this.x_speed = 0;
 this.y_speed = 0;
};

Paddle.prototype.render = function() {
 context.fillStyle = "white";
 context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};

function spelare1 () {
 this.Paddle = new Paddle(10, 275, 10, 75);
};
function spelare2 () {
 this.Paddle = new Paddle(880, 275, 10, 75);
}; 

spelare1.prototype.render = function () {
 this.Paddle.render();
}; 

spelare2.prototype.render = function () {
 this.Paddle.render();
}; 

function Ball(x, y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.x_speed = 0;
 this.y_speed = 3;
 this.radius = 4;
};

Ball.prototype.render = function() {
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = "white";
 context.fill();
}; 

var player1 = new spelare1(); 
var player2 = new spelare2(); 
var ball = new Ball(450, 300);
```

Comment: which is your function to see if they are in contact?

Comment: "Why this code is not working" is not a correct format of question in stack-overflow. You need to have a specific question/error.

Comment: @yBrodsky under "Ball.prototype.update = function(spelare1, spelare2)", "if(top_x > 900)".

Comment: Your paddles' position is dynamic. What I would do: create a new object which will be "The court". When you are creating this, you pass as a param the ball and the two paddles (the objects you have already created). Then once of the court's functions will be to check if there's a collition between the current ball position and the current paddles position, as well as the court's boundaries. If there's a collition, you will have to change the ball direction.